# I wish to display all posts that fall under a particular category in the sidebar

Tags: wordpress

I wish to display, in WordPress, all posts that fall under a particular category in the sidebar. How might I achieve my objective?

Comment: go in 'Appearance' -> 'Widgets' and add 'Categories' widget to your sidebar

Comment: i have already done but it is only showing main category not the posts titles.

Comment: did you at least search into the plugin registry before posting here?

Answer (score 0):

Write code something like this

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

                query_posts(
                        array(
                            'post_type'=>'post',
                            'posts_per_page'=>6,
                            'cat' => 4,
                            'orderby'=>'DESC',
                            'paged'=>$paged
                        )
                    );




                    if ( have_posts() ) { 
                                      while ( have_posts() ) {
                                      the_post();
                                  }
    }
```